# Challenging when having multiple ADFS Claims Providers

Tags: adfs

I see in UseWsFederationAuthentication that multiple Claims Providers can be specified.
My question is at Challenge time how do I specify which provider to use?
This is a winforms website.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

By default, With single claim provider , ADFS will proceed with available claim provider without prompting the selection page.

If you have more than one claim provider, ADFS will show the claim providers in the home realm page. You can select the right provider based on the user identity.

You will be able to customize the Home Realm Page, please look at the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/operations/home-realm-discovery-customization) for more scenario.